# What is the reason for this error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

**----------Error Full Text----------**

../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.22.08/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:11:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'FwfhTextStyle' is missing implementations for these members:

- TextStyle.fontVariations
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class FwfhTextStyle extends _TextStyleProxy {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Installion/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:789:33: Context: 'TextStyle.fontVariations' is defined here.
final List<ui.FontVariation>? fontVariations;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.22.08/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:43:13: Error: The method 'FwfhTextStyle.apply' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'TextStyle.apply'.
TextStyle apply({
^
/D:/Installion/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:911:13: Context: This is the overridden method ('apply').
TextStyle apply({
^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.22.08/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:43:13: Error: The method 'FwfhTextStyle.apply' doesn't have the named parameter 'fontVariations' of overridden method 'TextStyle
.apply'.
TextStyle apply({
^
/D:/Installion/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:911:13: Context: This is the overridden method ('apply').
TextStyle apply({
^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.22.08/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:103:13: Error: The method 'FwfhTextStyle.copyWith' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'TextStyle.copyWith
'.
TextStyle copyWith({
^
/D:/Installion/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:814:13: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
TextStyle copyWith({
^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.22.08/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:103:13: Error: The method 'FwfhTextStyle.copyWith' doesn't have the named parameter 'fontVariations' of overridden method 'TextS
tyle.copyWith'.
TextStyle copyWith({
^
/D:/Installion/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:814:13: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
TextStyle copyWith({
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Installion\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Installion\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please try it out by upgrading the dependency `flutter pub upgrade fwfh_text_style`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by upgrading fwfh_text_style

```
flutter pub upgrade fwfh_text_style
```

Answer (score 0):

it Looks Like the Class `_TextStyleProxy` Has Some Abstract Functions That u didn't implement in the child `FwfhTextStyle` after extending it with `_TextStyleProxy`.
implement the functions and the error should go away